# Perl HTML::TreeBuilder Class "Contains" Condition

Tags: perl, html-parsing

I'm trying to use Perls HTML::TreeBuilder to extract data from an HTML page. My selectors include the following:

```
$root->look_down(_tag => 'div', class => 'member-search-results');
```

However, the `div` I'm looking for has multiple classes, one of which is `member-search-results`. With this code, I'm unable to find the `div`, and need to list **all** of the classes to get a successful match.

Is there any way I can do a class *contains* search on the elements, so that the code can also match tags like:

```
<div class="CLASS1 member-search-results CLASS2">...</div>
```

I understand that this should work:

```
$root->look_down(_tag => 'div', class => qr/member-search-results/);
```

But is this the correct way of doing this or is there a better method?

Thanks

Comment: The `qr` regex solution looks like it's worth pursuing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Philip pointed out, using the regex method gets the desired results. Specifically, here is what I used:

```
$tag = $tag->look_down(_tag => 'ol', class => qr/members/);
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [Web::Query](http://p3rl.org/Web%3a%3aQuery) instead. Its CSS selectors are working according to the standards.

```
use Web::Query qw();
Web::Query
    ->new_from_html('<div class="CLASS1 member-search-results CLASS2">...</div>')
    ->find('div.member-search-results')
    ->text; # returns '...'
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you need to separate `_tag` and `class` into separate `look_down`'s (chain them together).

I use:

```
$tree->look_down( id => 'mw-content-text' )->look_down( _tag => 'ul' );
```

at https://github.com/pdurbin/scripts/blob/master/inthenews

Comment: Thanks! However, I'm unable to understand how this would help in this situation? Could you kindly elaborate a bit?

Comment: Ah, now that you've edited and clarified your question, I understand better and I think you're right that my example may not help your particular situation. If my answer is just noise, I can delete it for you.

Comment: Actually, it looks like you can use a regex: `(attr_name, qr/.../)` -- http://search.cpan.org/~cjm/HTML-Tree-5.03/lib/HTML/Element.pm#look_down